# Build jar file with gradle jibDockerBuild

Tags: java, spring, gradle

is it possible to build a jar file with a `gradle jibDockerBuild` command?

The problem that I have is that I want to run my application locally, and it is harder when I have to use a docker image.

So I am looking for a way to run/build my spring boot application locally using jib configuration than I have in `build.gradle.kts` file

Comment: Gradle can build jar files on its own just fine, why do you want to involve the jib plugin at all in this?

Comment: Because I have additional config when I attach using jib properties